# Does somebody know how to make a gradient background website that follows the window as you scroll?

Tags: html, css, background, gradient

Does somebody know how to make this happen? Im thinking about something like on the fireship website, but didn't manage to recreate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I pulled this from the source code:

```
body {
    background: linear-gradient(176deg,rgb(18,24,27) 50%,rgb(32,39,55) 100%);
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: You may need to be aware that some versions of IOS Safari do not implement background-attachment; fixed very well. If this is of concern, put the linear-gradient as background to a pseudo before element and fix that (positon: fixed)